# urllib.quote() throws KeyError

Tags: python, unicode, urllib2, urlencode, urllib

To encode the URI, I used `urllib.quote("schönefeld")` but when some non-ascii characters exists in string, it thorws

```
KeyError: u'\xe9'
Code: return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
```

My input strings are `köln, brønshøj, schönefeld` etc.

When I tried just printing statements in windows(Using python2.7, pyscripter IDE). But in linux it raises exception (I guess platform doesn't matter).

This is what I am trying:

```
from commands import getstatusoutput
queryParams = "schönefeld";
cmdString = "http://baseurl" + quote(queryParams)
print getstatusoutput(cmdString)
```

**Exploring the issue reason:**
in `urllib.quote()`, actually exception being throwin at `return ''.join(map(quoter, s))`.

The code in urllib is:

```
def quote(s, safe='/'):
    if not s:
        if s is None:
            raise TypeError('None object cannot be quoted')
        return s
     cachekey = (safe, always_safe)
     try:
         (quoter, safe) = _safe_quoters[cachekey]
     except KeyError:
         safe_map = _safe_map.copy()
         safe_map.update([(c, c) for c in safe])
         quoter = safe_map.__getitem__
         safe = always_safe + safe
         _safe_quoters[cachekey] = (quoter, safe)
      if not s.rstrip(safe):
         return s
      return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
```

The reason for exception is in `''.join(map(quoter, s))`, for every element in s, quoter function will be called and finally the list will be joined by '' and returned.

For non-ascii char `è`, the equivalent key will be `%E8` which presents in `_safe_map` variable. But when I am calling quote('è'), it searches for the key `\xe8`. So that the key does not exist and exception thrown.

So, I just modifed `s = [el.upper().replace("\\X","%") for el in s]` before calling `''.join(map(quoter, s))` within try-except block. Now it works fine.

But I am annoying what I have done is correct approach or it will create any other issue?
And also I do have 200+ instances of linux which is very tough to deploy this fix in all instances.

Comment: Is this Python 2 with unicode values? It works fine for already-encoded data.

Comment: You do *not* get an error for `urllib.quote('sch\xe9nefeld')`. You *only* get the error for `urllib.quote(u'sch\xe9nefeld')` (note the `u''` unicode literal).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so `cmdString = "http://baseurl" + quote("schönefeld")` this should be like `cmdString=u"http://baseurl"+quote(u"schönefeld")`?

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. I am stating that the error only occurs when you give `quote()` unicode values. For byte strings (already encoded) this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are trying to quote Unicode data, so you need to decide how to turn that into URL-safe bytes.

Encode the string to bytes first. UTF-8 is often used:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote(u'sch\xe9nefeld')
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py:1268: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1268, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\xe9'
>>> urllib.quote(u'sch\xe9nefeld'.encode('utf8'))
'sch%C3%A9nefeld'
```

However, the encoding *depends on what the server will accept*. It's best to stick to the encoding the original form was sent with.

Comment: utf-8 has stronger case than your answer implies. [All major browsers use utf-8](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/#iriworks) before percent-encoding while constructing URIs. [IRI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987) to [URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986) must be converted using utf-8. Other encodings are used on legacy servers.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sure, the path elements of URIs use UTF-8. But this is the query part instead. What a browser uses for encoding in the query string is less well defined, and has been, in the past, based on the encoding of the HTML page the form stems from.

Answer (score 2):

By just converting the string to unicode I resolved the issue.

here is the snippet:

```
try:
    unicode(mystring, "ascii")
except UnicodeError:
    mystring = unicode(mystring, "utf-8")
else:
    pass
```

Detailed description of solution can be found at http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error as @underscore but in my case the problem was that map(quoter,s) tried to look for the key `u'\xe9'` which was not in the `_safe_map`. However `\xe9` was, so I solved the issue by replacing `u'\xe9'` by `\xe9` in `s`.

Moreover, shouldn't the `return` statement be within the `try/except` ? I also had to change this to completely solve the problem.